# How should I call a player spell in a text RPG?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a mechanic that fills a vector with Spell objects, each with its own name, then select the spell with cin input and cast it on a target. What's the best way to do it? This is what I've done, but what if the spell has multiple spell effects?

```
//Spell.h
class Spell
{
public:
    enum e_spellType //enum with all spells
    {
        FIREBALL = 1,
        FROSTBOLT
    };

    enum e_spellEffect //enum with different effects
    {
        DAMAGE = 1, //for damaging effect
        SLOW
    };

    Spell(e_spellEffect effect);

    void returnSpellEffect(Unit* target);
    //getters here
    string getSpellName() const { return m_SpellName; }
    int getSpellValue() const { return m_SpellValue; }
    int getCooldown() const { return m_Cooldown; }
    int getManaCost() const { return m_ManaCost; }
protected:
    string m_SpellName;
    int m_SpellValue;
    int m_Cooldown;
    int m_ManaCost;
    int m_SpellID;
    e_spellEffect m_spellEffect;
    e_spellType m_spellType;
};

Spell::Spell(e_spellType type)
{
    m_spellType = type;
    switch (m_spellType)
    {
    case 1: //Fireball
        m_SpellValue = 35;
        m_ManaCost = 40;
        m_Cooldown = 2;
        m_spellEffect = DAMAGE;
    case 2: //Frostbolt
        m_SpellValue = 30;
        m_ManaCost = 40;
        m_Cooldown = 2;
        m_spellEffect = SLOW;
    }
}

void Spell::returnSpellEffect(Unit * target)
{
    switch (m_SpellEffect)
    {
    case DAMAGE:
        target->takeDamage(m_SpellValue);
        break;
    case SLOW:
        target->setDamage(0.5); //modifies Unit object's attack dmg to half
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

//Game.h
class Game
{
public:
    void enemyCombat();

protected:
    Player *player;
    vector<Enemy*> enemyList;
    vector<Spell*> spellList;

};

void Game::enemyCombat()
        {
//after you  have chosen a target from enemyList (enemyList[target])
spellList.push_back(new Spell(FIREBALL));
spellList.push_back(new Spell(FROSTBOLT));
    cout << "Choose a spell to cast:" << endl
            << "1. Fireball" << endl
            << "2. Frostbolt" << endl;
            int spellChoice = 0;
            cin >> spellChoice;
            spellList[spellChoice-1]->returnSpellEffect(enemyList[target]);
}
```

How do I make this whole thing more abstract to allow a spell to use more than one spell effect?

Comment: Important design thought:  do you really want to recompile your code to change the details of the effects?  How are you going to balance the game?  Details of spell effects like this should be flexibly after-market configurable (changeable without changing code).  Think: level-editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using polymorphism. If you have a virtual function `doSpellEffects`, you can implement "usual" logic in the base class, and more specialized logic in other classes for specific spells or spell categories.

```
class Spell
{
public:
    // Copying disabled to avoid slicing.
    Spell(const Spell&) = delete;
    Spell& operator=(const Spell&) = delete;
    virtual ~Spell() = default;

    enum e_spellType { /*...*/ };
    // TBD whether e_spellEffect belongs in Spell or SimpleSpell.

    // Factory function:
    static std::unique_ptr<Spell> create(e_spellType spellType);

    const std::string& getSpellName() const noexcept { return m_SpellName; }
    int getCooldown() const noexcept { return m_Cooldown; }
    int getManaCost() const noexcept { return m_ManaCost; }

    virtual void doSpellEffects(Unit* target) = 0;

protected:
    Spell(e_spellType spellType) :
        m_spellType(spellType), m_SpellName(),
        m_Cooldown(0), m_ManaCost(0) {}

    e_spellType m_spellType;
    std::string m_SpellName;
    int m_Cooldown;
    int m_ManaCost;
};

class SimpleSpell : public Spell
{
public:
    SimpleSpell(e_spellType spellType);
    void doSpellEffects(Unit* target) override;

    int getSpellValue() const { return m_SpellValue; }
protected:
    e_spellEffect m_spellEffect;
    int m_SpellValue;
};

class WarlocksRay : public Spell
{
public:
    WarlocksRay() : Spell(WARLOCKS_RAY, "Warlock's Ray") {}
    void doSpellEffects(Unit* target) override;
};
void WarlocksRay::doSpellEffects(Unit* target)
{
    // Two effects!
    target->takeDamage(5);
    target->stun();
}

// The factory function that creates all spells:
std::unique_ptr<Spell> Spell::create(e_spellType spellType) {
    switch(spellType) {
    case FIREBALL:
    case FROSTBOLT:
        return std::make_unique<SimpleSpell>(spellType);
    case WARLOCKS_RAY:
        return std::make_unique<WarlocksRay>();
    }
    // Invalid spellType: Log an error? Throw an exception? Just return nullptr?
    throw std::invalid_argument("Bad spellType in Spell::create");
}
```

You could use subclassing in other ways, which might or might not be worth it:

- Instead of a `switch` in `SimpleSpell::doSpellEffects`, create classes for each common effect type, like `DamageSpell` and `SlowSpell`.
- If the "cooldown" and/or "mana cost" mechanics might not apply to all spells, move these members and related logic out of `Spell` into a class `NormalCastingSpell` or something, which would come between `Spell` and other classes in the heirarchy.
- Even go so far as to create a class for each individual spell. In some cases, this could just inherit `SimpleSpell` or `DamageSpell` or etc., and the only member it would need to define would be a constructor that correctly sets all data members.

Answer (score 1):

[aschepler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459640/aschepler)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56817192/1312382) is probably the most flexible one, in worst case, though, you might end up in implementing every spell on its own. A variation of could be:

- a base class `Effect`
- deriving classes `DamageEffect`, `SlowEffect`, ...
- one single `Spell` class

The spell class then might look like this:

```
class Spell
{
    std::string name;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Effect>> effects;
public:
    void cast(Unit& target)
    {
        for(auto& effect : effects)
            effect->applyTo(target);
    }
}
```

When the spell gets casted, you likely would want to show some appropriate *visual* effect. You could again have polymorphic objects for these and provide one to the spell class as a member (several similar spells could re-use the same animation that way), alternatively you could have an animation for every effect and use the one of the first element in the effects vector.

Side note: You might create every spell just once in some global vector (not getting changed after creation any more, so no re-allocations – best have it `const`), units being able to cast spells would then just have pointers to those in their own vector.